# issue importing json file in r

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am trying to import the data from this api https://api.ycombinator.com/companies/export.json?callback=true

and i am getting the following error:

```
 Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   setupCompanies([{"name":"Parake
                 (right here) ------^
```

i thought the error was because of emoticons, so i downloaded the file as text and did the manual removal. It didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `?callback=true` from your URL, and it works without error:

```r
aa <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.ycombinator.com/companies/export.json")
str(aa)
# 'data.frame': 2055 obs. of  8 variables:
#  $ name       : chr  "Parakey" "Dinesafe" "Pengram" "Demeanor.co" ...
#  $ url        : chr  "http://parakey.com" "https://dinesafe.org" "http://pengramar.com" "https://demeanor.co" ...
#  $ batch      : chr  "s2005" "s2018" "w2019" "s2018" ...
#  $ vertical   : chr  NA "B2B" "Augmented Reality" "Media" ...
#  $ description: chr  "" "We crowdsource food poisoning reports and help detect and prevent outbreaks." "Pengram provides indoor navigation in augmented reality on your phone. " "Now part of thentwrk.com" ...
#  $ dead       : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
#  $ has_ff     : logi  NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
#  $ all_ff     : logi  NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

I'm guessing that the "callback API" is setting up the return value so that it is effectively a function call (i.e., `setupCompanies(...)`), not just data.